# How can I access model Relation with where condition of child and parent table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have Games table and which has the following schema

id | status | name

status column has 2 values (Active, Pending)

And GamePlayer table which has the following schema

id | game_id | player_id | request_status

request_status column has 3 values (Pending, Confirm, Rejected)

Now I have to select all game in which the player is involved but with the following constraints:

If the game is Pending state then it will be shown to all game_players
If the game is in Active state then it will be only shown to the game_player whose request_status is Confirm.
Game(Model)

```
public function GamePlayer()
{
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\GamePlayer', 'game_id', 'id');
}


public function getGames($playerId)
{
        $gameList = Game::with(['GamePlayer','Category:id,name'])
         ->whereHas('GamePlayer', function ($q) use ($playerId) {
                      $q->where('player_id', $playerId);
         })->get();
        return $gameList;
}
```

Controller

```
$this->gameObj = new Game();
$gameList = $this->gameObj->getGames($player_id);
```

Please help me out how can I populate data from another table based on condition(parent table as well as the child).

Comment: do you mean something like `join()` method?

Comment: Ya but using eloquent relation if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use condition in your relationship to get only confirmed game players

```
    public function activeGamePlayers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\GamePlayer', 'game_id', 'id')
            ->where('request_status', 'confirm');
    }
```

You can as well use scopes (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) to select only active games

```
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 'active');
        // You can then use $game->active()->...
    }
```

So your `getGame` would look like:

```
   public function getGames($playerId)
    {
        $player = GamePlayer::find($playerId);
        if ($player->status == 'active') {
            $gameList = Game::with(['GamePlayer', 'Category:id,name'])
                ->get();
        } else {
            $gameList = Game::with(['GamePlayer', 'Category:id,name'])
                ->active()->get();
        }
        return $gameList;
    }
```

**NOTE:**

in your specific case, I would instead get started from the GamePlayer Model to get the games, instead of coming from the Game Model - you can use scopes and conditions in relationships as well to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel method `whereHas`. You should read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) part of Laravel the documentation.
Note that you should have relationships declared on every model.